# replacing integers in a data frame (logic issues)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So I am trying to change some values in a df using pandas and, having already tried with `df.replace`, `df.mask`, and `df.where` I got to the conclusion that it must be a logical mistake since it keeps throwing the same mistake:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous.
```

I am trying to normalize a column in a dataset, thus the function and not just a single line. I need to understand why my logic is wrong, it seems to be such a dumb mistake.

This is my function:

```
def overweight_normalizer():
    if df[df["overweight"] > 25]:
        df.where(df["overweight"] > 25, 1)
    elif df[df["overweight"] < 25]:
        df.where(df["overweight"] < 25, 0)
```

Comment: Does it matter if the function does not take in df as an argument?

Comment: Try to use `loc` function: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`df[df["overweight"] > 25]` is not a valid condition.

Try this:

```
def overweight_normalizer():
    df = pd.DataFrame({'overweight': [2, 39, 15, 45, 9]})
    df["overweight"] = [1 if i > 25 else 0  for i in df["overweight"]]
    return df

overweight_normalizer()
```

Output:

```
    overweight
0           0
1           1
2           0
3           1
4           0
```